# Parse Blockly generated XML code to Java objects

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, blockly

I've to parse Blockly generated XML code. Generally i use Xstream parser for parsing XML. But XStream parser not working since this XML has child tags same name as Parent tag. 
I found [this](https://github.com/Vilsol/Blockly2Java) library which converts Blockly xml code to Java objects. But this library fails for Complex Blockly XML code shown below. I tried to edit library to enable parsing for the below xml code. But its not working.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<block type="event_click" id="Bp64nx|xcR*L:(K(`u78" x="146" y="81">
   <field name="Event_Type">none</field>
   <field name="do_on_page_load">TRUE</field>
   <statement name="action">
      <block type="database_yes_no" id="@0OCYIX:}@uT?0[UbS=r">
         <value name="Check_Name">
            <block type="database_check_field" id="Sl-IEwB~/hv?9mQYYBB]">
               <field name="Enum_Name">StockType</field>
               <field name="Enum_Value">Serialised</field>
            </block>
         </value>
         <statement name="Yes">
            <block type="action_toggle_field" id="}X:#xcfp,!+bk7MA.sgJ">
               <field name="action">show</field>
               <field name="id">4930</field>
               <next>
                  <block type="action_toggle_field" id="h)QgD#prJCVcm;BMG$VR">
                     <field name="action">hide</field>
                     <field name="id">4932</field>
                     <next>
                        <block type="action_toggle_field" id="1V{g?Cdh2ww}ihWhtovG">
                           <field name="action">show</field>
                           <field name="id">4961</field>
                        </block>
                     </next>
                  </block>
               </next>
            </block>
         </statement>
         <statement name="No">
            <block type="action_toggle_field" id="InDTOg;B2!go_rD;WIb~">
               <field name="action">hide</field>
               <field name="id">4930</field>
               <next>
                  <block type="action_toggle_field" id="f{Ae_|^jEb{CR5$?9Ku.">
                     <field name="action">show</field>
                     <field name="id">4932</field>
                     <next>
                        <block type="action_toggle_field" id="@-^o/f|Iv0WIids+VcJv">
                           <field name="action">hide</field>
                           <field name="id">4961</field>
                        </block>
                     </next>
                  </block>
               </next>
            </block>
         </statement>
      </block>
   </statement>
</block>
```

I don't see much help on Blockly xml parsing.

Please let me know if there is a solution or library to parse Blockly generated XML code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Stream-based XML parsers require you to maintain extra state, usually a stack. Simple `if (tagName == 'block') {...}` is not sufficient.

For your above example, the stack might look like:

```
block
statement
block
statement
block
next
block
next
block
field
```

Each item might have a pointer to the parsed object under construction, so you can add the child to it, and know what object to continue working on after an end tag.

While it uses XmlPullParser instead of a stream parser, you may want to look at [`com.google.blockly.model.BlockFactory.fromXml(..)`](https://github.com/google/blockly-android/blob/develop/blocklylib-core/src/main/java/com/google/blockly/model/BlockFactory.java#L456) in the [`blockly-android`](https://github.com/google/blockly-android) repo.